# Convergence of the recursive sequence $x_n = x_{n-1} - \frac12\lambda(x_{n-1}-1)^{-3/2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, divergent-series

Let $\lambda \geq 0$ and define the recursive sequence
$$
x_n = x_{n-1} - \frac{\lambda}{2(x_{n-1}-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
I know that this sequence is bounded below by 1 and I also need to determine a starting point $x_0$ such that the serie converges (maybe expressed as a function of $\lambda$).
I start setting up the problem, by using the inequality
$$
1 \leq x - \frac{\lambda}{2(x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \leq x
$$
However, I have absolutely no idea about how to handle such inequality.
Thanks to anybody willing to help! :)

Comment: That is the Newton's iteration applied to... which function? Can you solve the separable DE $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{2}{\lambda}(x-1)^{3/2}$$ ?

Comment: Yep, the solution is $-\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{x-1}}$... but how can I use it in order to solve the problem?

Comment: At first, you spoke about a sequence and then you say the serie?

Comment: "I know that this sequence is bounded below by 1" Hmmm, no. The full sequence is not defined, since, if $\lambda>0$, then, for every $x_0>1$, after a  while, one gets $x_n\leqslant1$ and then, what is $x_{n+1}$?

Comment: The solution is not that. Specifically, what do you know about Newton's method applied to a positive convex function?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Yep, the solution to the problem is $f(x) = \exp{\{\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{x-1}} + \frac{x^2}{2}\}}$... But now I don't know where do you want to go... I don't know anything about Newton's method applied to "positive convex" functions... Please, can you explain better your argument?

Comment: "I know that this sequence is bounded below by 1" Is it? Could you explain the argument, even briefly?

Comment: The above is the gradient descent algorithm for the function $\sqrt{|x-1|}$ for positive values of $x$. When choosing an appropriate step size $\lambda$ the algorithm converges to the stationary point $x=1$.

Comment: @james42 This is delusional. If $x_n$ is close enough to $1$ then either $x_{n+1}<0$ or $x_{n+1}>2$, so, which convergence are you talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

as we have

$$x_{n}=x_{n-1}-\frac{\lambda}{2(x_{n-1}-1)^\frac32}$$

if $(x_n)$ converges to $L$ then

we will have

$$L=L-\frac{\lambda}{2(L-1)^\frac32}$$

impossible if $\lambda>0$ and $(x_n)$ diverges.

if $\; \lambda=0\;  \;x_n=x_0=C^t$

Comment: No, the n th element of the sequence converges for small values of $\lambda$, I have checked it with a computer

Comment: @james42 The computer cannot do everything.

Comment: This answer correctly indicates (after some revision) why the sequence $(x_n)$ cannot converge to any finite limit.